# Диалоги с ботом на php

Tags: php, бот

Пишу бота для вк, я стажер)
Возник вопрос, как сделать диалоги с ботом т.е, есть например такой выбор:

Выберите услугу :
   -1) Пополнения услуг связи
   -2)Погашения кредита
и вот юзер пишет боту цифру 1 например

ему выдает диалог например

```
Выберите оператора
!мтс
!мегафон
```

и вот как сделать такие диалоги чтобы нельзя было написать боту команду например "!мтс" и сразу пополнить счет без вызова 1 диалога

Comment: Вариантов много. Но лучше сразу реализовать машину состояний в боте. В каждом конкретном состоянии будете принимать только определённые команды, а на остальные не реагировать.

Comment: пример можно???